# can not create Android client id

Tags: android, google-app-engine

My apologies for asking this question on Stackoverflow, but Google says that this is my only choice.  I have a support package from Google in theory, but all attempts to get a PIN yield "Invalid Operation" (a different problem).

I am just trying to use the Google web page instructions to create an Android client Id for secure access to AppEngine Endpoints.

In the following Google instructions, steps 6 and 7 point me to non-existent user choices on the Google Cloud console.

Straight from the web page:

[https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth#Java_Creating_OAuth_20_client_IDs]

...

Creating an Android client ID

...

1. Open the Google Cloud Console. [https://cloud.google.com/console]
2. When your project appears in the projects pulldown menu, select it to make it the active project.  [Selected the project from the table of projects]
3. Click APIs and Auth and select Registered Apps  [No such selections exist; tried all links - nothing even close to on topic.]
4. If your app is not yet registered, select the Register App button.  [No such link exists.]

…

I hope Google is listening and can help.  My apologies to everyone else.  I have no other way to contact Google.

Comment: I believe those instructions apply to the new cloud console.  Are you by chance still using the old api console?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's the issue, as the instruction provided is correct and that's how we generated the client ID for our projects:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, however, my project does not have the APIs & auth set of menu items...

Comment: For whatever reason my original AppEngine project was not setup correctly.  The resolution seems to be to create a new project, which works, and you get the above menus.   And then just delete the old non-functional project.   The drawback it that you have to create a new App Id.